# How to delete app with CF CLI when error occurs

Tags: swisscomdev

Deleting an app with `cf delete` shows the following error:

```
Deleting app the-app in org my-org / space my-space as me@mail.com...
FAILED
Server error, status code: 502, error code: 10001, message: Service broker failed to delete service binding for instance my-service:
Service broker error: Internal Server Error
```

Swisscom status shows no errors, and there doesn't appear to be any additional info about what we should do.

Comment: what service is binded to this app? How is the marketplace name?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing you can do other than trying again later. But most likely you'll need assistance of their support because something unexpected is going wrong.